# Поменять ссылки на утерянные картинки

Tags: jquery

Имею галерею лайтбокс.

```
<ul class="gallery">
<li><a href="http://newdomain.ru/images/30652.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox-atomium"> 
<img src="http://newdomain.ru/images/30652t.jpg"> 
</a>   
</li>
</ul>
```

Необходимо при утерянной ссылке на большую картинку, заменить её адрес со старого домена.
Пишу на jQuery - не работает. Что я делаю не так

```
<script>
     $('a').on('error',function(){ 
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('newdomain', 'olddomain'));      
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как Вы полагаете, в какой момент должно произойти событие `error` на элементе `а`?

```
$(".gallery li a").each(function(i, a) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.onerror = function() {
    $(a).attr('href', $(a).attr('href').replace('newdomain', 'olddomain')); 
  };
  img.style.display = "none";
  img.src = $(a).attr('href');
  a.appendChild(img);
});
```